# How can I load a webpage from cache for offline browsing in Google Chrome browser?

Tags: chrome-for-android, offline

In Google Chrome browser running on an Android phone, I opened a webpage under wifi. Now I am disconnected from WiFi, I want to access the webpage loaded before from the cache, but it shows "No Internet" instead. can I see the webpage loaded before from the cache?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you have to manually save the webpage from Chrome. A cache by itself might not sufficient because some sites prevent caching altogether.

Comment: I remember when no wifi connection, it automatically enters offline browsing mode?